# How to write a single Folder name with all the files in it in a text file in DOS?

Tags: dos

Suppose i have a folder structure which has a path like this..
C:\Fold1\Fold2\Fold3\Sample.xls

I want to display the File name i.e Sample.xls in a separate text file along with the Last folder name. That is Fold3

Output in Text file should be like this..

Fold 3
Sample.xls

Please need the code ASAP...

Answer (score 0):

I would do a pure Dir /B in a temp file and then use some awk or grep solution to extract the part I need with regular expressions.

There are many free tools to allow this (GNU for Windows).